# How to fix android studio image view errors?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to upload a photo using an android studio. but I get this error. What is that? How to fix it?

> error: incompatible types: no unique maximal instance exists for type
>   variable T with upper bounds ImageView,View where T is a
>   type-variable: T extends View declared in method findViewById(int)

```
B_image_View = B_image_View = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
```

Comment: The problem is that your using the method `findViewById`wich takes an int (the view id) and you giving it the view.

Comment: Please rewrite and show me? @JPeter

Comment: @ChalanaJayasinghe What's the name of your Activity? Could you please share the whole activity's code?